# How can I setup a redirect using an .htaccess that would keep part of the URL path?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, path

I would like to setup a redirect using an *.htaccess* file which keeps part of the URL's path in the target URL. For example:

I have the domain `example.com`. I want `example.com/social` to redirect to `twitter.com`. BUT if someone types in `example.com/social/Bob` I want it to redirect to `twitter.com/Bob`, and would like it to work the same way for any value entered after the `/social/` directory.

What might I add to an .htaccess file in order to do this?

Comment: I edited this to be less broad, and specific to doing this with an _.htaccess_ file in order to make it on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^social(.*) https://twitter.com$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yeah, it needed the / removing before social but it works great after that :)

Comment: A start of string anchor (ie. `^`) is required on the `RewriteRule` pattern in order to avoid any ambiguity. ie. `^social(.*)`. Otherwise it will match URLs that simply _contain_ the word "social".

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I updated the answer to include your suggestion.